# Is it possible to merge two screen sessions chained?

Tags: gnu-screen, tty

Let us imagine I have only one terminal. To overcome this trouble I use `screen`, so happy!

However, I need to connect to another computer over `ssh`, to prevent to open several connections I want to run `screen` on this window, but if I do that I'll have problems with key binding. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass commands from one screen sessions to it's sub-screen session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> (it send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to the sub-screen)

For example:

- To detach the sub-screen: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>
- Go to the next screen: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>
- Go to the previous screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>

Comment: It worked, despite it is not so easy.